# Setting Minimum Value to a Substraction (AngularJS)

Tags: html, angularjs

I would like to know how it is possible to set a minimum value of "0" to my substration (`100 - message.length`). I don't want negative values to be returned when the minimum number of caracteres (100) is verified (For instance: "Number of caracteres left: -55"). Thank you.

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="message" ng-model="message"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">Number of caracteres left: {{100 - message.length}}
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="(!message || message.length < 100)">Send</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this `{{100 - message.length>0?100 - message.length:0}}`

Comment: Easiest than I thought! Thank you :)